# These 2 appear to be Base64 but theres a / . What code is it and how do I decode it?

Tags: base64, decode

These 2 appear to be Base64 but theres a / . What code is it and how do I decode it?

UoOB4vcxYN/cmzwTK6rUGXNlvnlUTUN8d4/eZg==

uTHjqhp1GkseZtI3fyuKpX0wA/CaoaIBNJyQRbDi48E=

Thanks in advance

Comment: '/' is a valid character in Base64 encoding. What is the problem?

Comment: `/` is a valid character in base64.

Comment: @pedrofb  Thank you, I have reason to believe they are encrypted codes. If so, how do I decode their meaning? And if not, what would these be used for, keys?

Comment: Base64 is not an encryption algorithm. You can decode it with any converter e.g. https://www.base64decode.org/. If the decoded content is encrypted, then you will probably need to know the algorithm and key

Comment: Thank you once again pedrofb :)